# Nohup take no effect when to close the terminal end the process running in background?

Tags: bash, nohup

`nohup command &` can keep a command running after closing the terminal.
I want to play all mp3 music in directory `Music`.

```
ls Music/*mp3 |xargs -d "\n" mplayer
```

`ls Music/*mp3` can list all mp3 files in directory `Music`, send it via pipe with xargs, `-d "\n"` is to treat blanks in the filenames.

I want to redirect all `stdout` and `stderr` into `/dev/null`, and run it in the background.

```
ls Music/*mp3 |xargs -d "\n" mplayer > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

This works fine, but I want it running after closing the terminal.

```
nohup ls Music/*mp3 | xargs -d "\n" mplayer > /dev/null 2>&1 &
ls Music/*mp3 | xargs -d "\n" nohup mplayer > /dev/null 2>&1 &
ls Music/*mp3 | nohup xargs -d "\n" mplayer > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

When I close the terminal, the process running in the background ends.
Why does `nohup` not take effect in any of the above three commands? How can I make it take effect?

`disown` can solve the issue, but I would like a solution using `nohup`.

```
ls Music/*mp3 | xargs -d "\n" mplayer > /dev/null 2>&1 & disown
```

Comment: `disown` is equivalent with `nohup` ,how to fix it with `nohup` then?

Comment: you need put `nohup` before `xargs` in this case, because it's `xargs` who will recieve `HUP` signal when terminal is closed.

Comment: `Put nohup before xargs`  takes no effect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`nohup command`](https://manpages.debian.org/nohup.1) means "run `command` and ignore [HUP signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP)".

So before we can effectively use `nohup` we need to ask: when and how is `SIGHUP` sent? As the Bash manual says, ["Before exiting, an interactive shell resends the SIGHUP to all jobs, running or stopped."](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Signals.html). It goes on to say that the proper way to suppress this behavior is with `disown`. I realize you are asking about `nohup`, but it's worth calling out that `disown` is the intended and easier way to accomplish what you want. Note that `disown` is *not* equivalent to `nohup`.

The reason `nohup` is tricky to work with here is because it applies to a single process, whereas `&` creates a background [job](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Definitions.html#index-job) of a whole command [pipeline](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html), which can consist of multiple processes. This means you need to `nohup` each command in the pipeline in order to ensure that the individual commands don't receive a SIGHUP, e.g.:

```
$ nohup ls Music/*mp3 2>/dev/null | nohup xargs -d "\n" nohup mplayer &> /dev/null &
```

This *should* work, though I haven't tested it with these specific commands. If it doesn't, it's likely another process that you aren't starting directly is still receiving a SIGHUP. This is harder to address, which is exactly why we have `disown`.

manishg's suggestion is also reasonable; by moving the pipeline into a separate process you can `nohup` *that* process, which should in turn prevent a SIGHUP from reaching its children when your shell closes.

---

All that said, you don't need `ls` and `xargs` here in the first place; `find` can be used to similar effect and will simplify reasoning about the command. Try:

```
$ nohup find Music -maxdepth 1 -name '*mp3' -exec mplayer {} + &> /dev/null &
```

Answer (score 4):

> I want to play all mp3 music in directory Music.

Usually, you don't need `ls` or `xargs` for that.
You can simplify your whole pipeline to `mplayer Music/*mp3` ✱.
This is not only safer for special filenames, but also solves your problem with `nohup`:

```
nohup mplayer Music/*mp3 &> /dev/null &
```

<sub>✱ There is only one case where this command fails and `ls * | xargs` succeeds. If you have a very large number of mp3 files you might run into the command line length limit. The limit in bytes is given by `getconf ARG_MAX`. On my system it is 2097152, meaning you would need at least 8000 files assuming a maximum file name length of 255 bytes. With shorter file names, you can have even more files. For instance, if your mp3 files are usually around 40 bytes long, you can use more than 44000 files.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

There are two way to close the terminal.
`exit` way:

Input `exit` in terminal and click `enter`.

`cross` way:
Click the `cross` at the upper right corner.

To illustrate them with same png file.
[image]
`nohup` can take effect only with `exit` way for all the following command(checked everyone at least three times in terminal).

```
ls Music/*mp3 |xargs -d "\n" nohup mplayer  > /dev/null 2>&1 &
ls  Music/*mp3 | nohup  xargs  -d  "\n"  mplayer  > /dev/null  2>&1  &
nohup ls Music/*mp3 2>/dev/null | nohup xargs -d "\n" nohup mplayer &> /dev/null &
nohup find Music -maxdepth 1 -exec mplayer {} \; &> /dev/null &
nohup mplayer Music/*mp3 &> /dev/null &
```

A little bug for both `nohup sh -c`  and `nohup bash -c`:

```
nohup sh -c 'ls  Music/*mp3 |  xargs  -d  "\n"  mplayer' &
[1] 4581
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'
nohup bash -c 'ls  Music/*mp3 |  xargs  -d  "\n"  mplayer' &
[1] 16831
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'
```

When to close terminal with `cross` way ,music will not play in background for all above command.

The command ending with `disown` will go on to play the music in background with whatever way (`exit` or `cross` way).
It is better to exec `disown` command in order to go on to play music in background after closing the terminal.

Comment: Hitting the `x` in the corner likely sends a SIGTERM and not a SIGHUP. `nohup` only suppresses SIGHUP, by design.

Comment: I think nohup is a safer choice as there is no "beautiful way" to reclaim a disowned process.

Answer (score 0):

nohup doesn’t work like this with pipes. use the following way:

```
nohup sh -c 'ls  Music/*mp3 |  xargs  -d  "\n"  mplayer' &
```

Comment: `sh` ought to work fine in this example, but for consistency I'd suggest `bash -c` instead of `sh -c`. It's generally unintended, and sometimes wrong, to invoke `sh` from a `bash` script.

Comment: nohup bash -c 'ls  Music/*mp3 |  xargs  -d  "\n"  mplayer' &
[1] 16831

Comment: $ nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'

Answer (score 0):

You should wait `nohup` transfer the parent process to `PID 1`.

```bash
$ nohup [YOUR COMMAND] 2>&1 &
nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'
$ #usually this appeared then you can exit safely
$ sleep 1
$ exit
```

Exit too early may cause the parent process of command and itself be killed.